# Launch android app from python script?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I have the following in /sdcard/sl4a/scripts/imo.py

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
droid.launch('com.imo.android.imoim')
```

And if I run it , it immediately exits.
If there are other ways to launch applications from some sort of script, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It will be very helpful to specify what library did you use

Comment: How are you executing this? From the phone itself?

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty easy if you are using sl4a

```
import sl4a
droid=sl4a.Android()
droid.launch('com.imo.android.imoim')
```