# How to open other applications through Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

I have a decent hold on Python, but completely new to developing android applications. Hence, I thought of using Kivy, as I do know Python.

I wish to create an application that includes a button, and on clicking the button, the user is redirected to a specific application(maybe Messages, or YouTube, etc.)

As I'm currently coding on my pc, I figured out how to redirect the user to a specific website by clicking a button, but I'm clueless when it comes to the above problem.

Any help with this regard would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609971/launch-android-app-from-python-script

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows box you can do:

```
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
            command = 'explorer "' + file_name + '"'
            p = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

This will allow windows to handle opening a file correctly.

You can also use `Popen` on Linux systems, but I think you will have to determine the specific app that you waant to open.